# AngularJS handling Server HTTP 403/40X

Tags: angularjs

I have standard functions in my frontend AngularJS 1.x application (with ui-route) which looks like the one at bottom. 
My question now would be what to do if e.g. HTTP 403 appears. Is there a best practive approach how to redirect to loginpage in AngularJS.
I would be thankful for all hints in this direction.

Thanks a lot!

```
function getSomethingFromServer(someParameters) {
        return $http.get(api_config.BASE_URL + ...', {              
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log('got data from server');
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log('error getting data from server'); // in my case HTTP 403 appears if token is not valid any more
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the the $http service in the angular docs and in particular response interceptors - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http